# Can anyone solve this 8080 assembly code 'puzzle'?

Tags: assembly, machine-code, intel-8080

A friend of mine was given 8080 assembly code as part of a puzzle he's trying to solve.
This is the code:

```
3E 02
4F
C6 04
47
11 41 01
21 69 00
19
76
```

He needs the values of B, DE, C and HL

Can anyone solve this or point me in the right direction on how to run this?

**Update**

Spoiler: The solution seems to be:

> C = 02, B = 06, D = 01, E = 41, H = 01, L = AA

Comment: I only remember 21 and 11 which are LD HL and LD DE instructions respectively :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a guide to the 8080 instruction set:
http://www.comsci.us/cpu/8080/isindex.html
Your hex listing looks like an instruction stream; you should be able to go from there. How delightfully old-school!

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here's the disassembly:

```
 3E 02      mvi     a, 2     ; Move o1 <- immediate data
 4F         mov     c, a     ; Move o1 <- o2
 C6 04      adi     4        ; Add immediate to A
 47         mov     b, a     ; Move o1 <- o2
 11 41 01   lxi     d, 141h  ; Load register pair with immediate data
 21 69 00   lxi     h, 69h   ; Load register pair with immediate data
 19         dad     d        ; Add register pair to HL
 76         hlt              ; Halt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to disassemble it.

That is, convert the hex op codes in to their mnemonics.

Here's an example [reference](http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html).

You can see from this that 3E is "MVI A, d8", so that looks like 3E 02 is putting the value 02 in to the A register.

Once you've decoded the mnemonics, you can look up what they actually mean and figure out the program.

Easy enough to do by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Complete spoiler

> ```
> 0000h: 3e02         mvi a, 2h      ; A = 2
> ```
>
> ```
> 0002h: 4f           mov c, a       ; C = 2
> ```
>
> ```
> 0003h: c604         adi 4h         ; A = 6
> ```
>
> ```
> 0005h: 47           mov b, a       ; B = 6
> ```
>
> ```
> 0006h: 114101       lxi d, 141h    ; DE = 0141h
> ```
>
> ```
> 0009h: 216900       lxi h, 069h    ; HL = 69h
> ```
>
> ```
> 000ch: 19           dad d          ; HL = 69h + 141h = 1aah
> ```
>
> ```
> 000dh: 76           hlt
> ```
>
> A = 6, B = 6, C = 2, D = 1, E = 41h, H = 1, L = 0aah

An 8080 online disassembler [here](http://desperate-programmers.com/online-disassembler/).
An 8080 online instruction set reference [here](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/computers/tandy/software/apps/m4/qd/opcodes.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run it - you just need to translate it. A table of 8080 opcodes [like this](http://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html), 10 minutes work and you will have disassembled the code. You can then simulate it mentally to work out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this, your best bet would be to do a search for an 8080 emulator and run it against the emulator, and get the answer from it.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Unless, of course, his "friend" will be expected to do this manually, say, on a test, some time in the future. =)

Comment: I would personally scream at any professor who would require something like this for a test.

Comment: @David: Good luck to memorizing the opcodes.... :) lol so cruel if that's to be expected...

Comment: Actually, I used to know most of the Z80 (and so also 8080) opcodes in hex  by heart - I never sat down and learned them, but months hunched over an assembler and debugger engrained them in my mind. Almost all gone now, of course.

Comment: I worked intimately with 8051s back in the day and accidentally memorized many, many opcodes. When I was in undergrad we had to hand disassemble machine code on an exam, but we had a 68hc11 reference manual that happily listed opcodes, flags, parameters, etc. Insert shudder here.

Answer (score 1):

```
3E 02      ;mvi a, 02h    -- load A with 02h
4F         ;mov c,a       -- move A into C (A remains 02h)
C6 04      ;adi 04h       -- a = a + 04h  (A now contains 06h)
47         ;mov b,a       -- BC pair now contains 0602h
11 41 01   ;lxi d, 0414h  -- DE now contains 0141h
21 69 00   ;lxi h, 0069h  -- HL now contains 0069h
19         ;dad d         -- HL = HL + DE
76         ;hlt           -- halt processing
```